# Java - difference null vs empty

Tags: java

What is the difference between initialising to `null` or empty:

```
Type name = null;
Type name;
```

Is there any difference at all?

I understand that for example:

```
String name = null;
String name = "";
```

The difference would be that the first one does not initialise it to any value and the other one does, but is there are any **difference between the first two**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Type name = null;
Type name;
```

default value for any reference variable is `null` so no difference

if it is defined into some local scope then it will give you compiler error if you attempt to access it before initializing it

Answer (score 2):

The only difference that I know of is if you declare the variable in a local scope and not in class scope, the compiler will complain if you try to use the variable before some initialization for the latter. Otherwise there is no difference that I know.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no difference. If you do not assign a default value, the variable is automatically considered `null`.